# Is it possible to create a CSS only menu that opens and closes with a click and that closes when the mouse leaves?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have been trying to build a CSS only menu.
This menu should be able to:

- be opened by clicking it
- be closed by clicking it
- be closed when the mouse cursor leaves the menu.

Is it possible to do so? It seems to me that the last point can't be included successfully. Thanks in  advance for any help!

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Paulie_D Oh, I have been researching and trying. The only solution that I found east to implement JavaScript

Comment: Well that should tell you something. "clicks" require Javascript.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's not true. You can use a checkbox and a label to do it only with css. But it is the combination the conditions that I am not able to do

Answer (score 0):

Here (https://w3bits.com/css-html-menu/) you can find more information on how to create a CSS only menu.